# Template in C++ is doing something I didn't expect

Tags: c++, templates

This code is giving me the output:

```
The sqrt of 1.234 is: 1.52276 why is this diffrent from: 1.11086 1.11086
```

Why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
T sqrt(T x)
{
    return x*x;
}

template<typename T>
void print_sqrt(T x)
{
    double tmp = sqrt(x);
    cout << "The sqrt of " << x << " is: " << sqrt<double>(x) << " why is this diffrent from: " << sqrt(x) << " " << tmp << endl;
}


int main()
{
    print_sqrt<double>(1.234);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: [Triple face palm!](http://worldseriesdreaming.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/blog3-1024x576.jpg)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `std::sqrt` function (which is what you are calling when not providing a template argument) calculates the square root, while your version computes the square.

Comment: This is also one of those cases in which one can see why `using namespace std;` is not the best practice.

Comment: How would omitting it have helped in the face of this particular logic error?